# How to modify the function to satisfy OCP?

Tags: c, open-closed-principle

The following function is implemented in C:

```
function(struct_XX *p)
{
    if(p->A)
    {
        if(p->B)
        {
            do something0;
        }
        if(p->C)
        {
            do something1;
        }
        if(p->D && p->E)
        {
            do something2;
        }
          if(p->Z)
        {
            do something3;
        }
    }
}
```

each branch has different things to do,It doesn't satisfy Open-Closed Principle(because the struct which p points at is not stable ,new fields will be added into it often,that means new process codes will be added into **function** frequently); how can it be modified to satisfy OCP?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Are the 'do something's all the same thing, or are they each different?  Do any of the 'do something's modify what `p` points at?  What is the significance of the '`¡­¡­`' in the code?  Why doesn't the function have a return type?

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to suggest anything useful. OCP requires that your code provides mechanisms to extend the functionality. What mechanism(s) does your code provide to extend the core functionality?

Comment: Are you free to change 'struct_XX's definition or if it is fixed, show it to us.

Comment: In C you might use function pointers. Look inside GTK and its  [gobject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) layer for inspiration.

Comment: "It doesn't satisfy Open-Closed Principle" -- Says who? You haven't even mentioned the semantics of `function`. Please don't ask questions at SO when you don't even understand what your question is about.

Answer (score 2):

you haven't given much to go, you have a bunch of conditions, and a bunch of "do"s based on those conditions.

So given that... you can make something that stores a collections of conditions and callbacks....

```
void ocpfunction(struct struct_XX *p)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<p->conditions_count; i++) 
   { 
      if(p->conditions[i].evaluate(p))
      {
          p->conditions[i].callback(p, p->conditions[i].context);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: So is p->conditions a struct or an array?

Comment: conditions would be an array of structs with function pointers for callbacks and evaluations